# Two events from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row of 8 buttons that show/hide content below them depending on the button selection. That part's working fine. The other thing I want to happen is to scroll down to the selection - the buttons are right at the bottom of the screen, and while clicking a button does swap out the content, people don't see it happening without scrolling to it themselves. So I created an element between the buttons and the content and gave it an id of "scroll-down-to-sections." and added the last line here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".tab-title").each(function () {
    var section_id = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(this).find("a").removeAttr("href");
    $(this).click(function () {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("active-tab");
      $(this).addClass("active-tab");
      $(".tab-content").slideUp(500);
      $(section_id).slideDown(500);
      $("html, body").animate(
        { scrollBottom: $("#scroll-down-to-sections").offset().top },
        1000
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Works great, but the last line isn't working, and I'm sure it should. Any ideas?

Comment: without the HTML it's a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

I revised the last line to:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#scroll-down-to-sections").offset().top}, 1000);
```

and it works as intended. Sorry for the lame post!